# Making Https request from the flutter app?

Tags: api, http, flutter, dart, https

I have my API's deployed in server and I can make either of HTTP, https requests to hit the APIs.
I've tested apis by making http requests. like

```
String loginURL="https://<ip>/login/auth";
http.Response response = await http.post(loginURL,
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
          body: json.encode({"username": username, "password": password}));
```

If I done the http request I am getting the response with success code as 200

But when I tried to hit the same API which is deployed with https. I am getting the exception in the server not receiving any response. How to make a https request?

Comment: Is the server certificate trusted by a certificate in the trust store? Or is it self-signed?

Comment: Its self-signed

Comment: Ok, then you are properly getting an invalid certificate error unless you trust it in the Android OS.

Comment: I executed the code in the android simulator, but I am not able to log in, it's showing the could not connect error message from the catch block, How to trust on the android device

Comment: and while hitting the api from postman I am not receiving the response, then I turned off SSL certificate verification then I got the response

Answer (score -1):

Use this HTTP template

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RegisterApi {
 static Future<Map> login(String email, String password, String name) async {
   var url =
      'xxxxxxxxxx';

var header = {
  "Content-type": "application/json",
  "key": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

Map params = {
  "anunciante_name": name,
  "anunciante_pass": password,
  "anunciante_email": email
};

try {
  var _body = json.encode(params);

  var response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: _body);

  var data = json.decode(response.body);

  return data;
   } catch (e) {
   return null;
  }
 }
}
```

[This link will also help](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef)

Comment: The question is for HTTPS and not HTTP request any one has any solution for HTTPS request ?